# What is the time period for "Period::days(1)" in laravel analytics?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If i make a request like this in spatie analytics:

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(1),
    'ga:sessions',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:yearMonth'
    ]
);
```

what does "days(1) refer to ? is it from 00:00 to 23:59 or from 24 hour ago until now?

i tried reading the start and end time in the result but it is not provided.

Comment: If you read the [source](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Period.php#L20) it indicates that it's start of day of 1 day ago to start of day today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [code](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/blob/master/src/Period.php#L24), the period begins at the start of the day.

```php
public static function days(int $numberOfDays): static
{
    $endDate = Carbon::today();
    $startDate = Carbon::today()->subDays($numberOfDays)->startOfDay();
    return new static($startDate, $endDate);
}
```

From the [Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers), `today()` and `startOfDay()` return midnight-aligned datetime values:

```php
$today = Carbon::today();
echo $today;                             // 2021-07-01 00:00:00

$dt = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 31, 12, 0, 0);
echo $dt->startOfDay();                  // 2012-01-31 00:00:00
```